# ReadyRead Signal on QUdpSocket only emitted if bind method called first

Tags: qt, pyqt, qudpsocket

Using PyQt4 and Qt4.1, Python 3.7.2, latest PyInstaller

I have two applications (c++ and python) which communicate via udp localhost, port 2340 and port 2341)
On both applications I am bounding the ports with

```
self.SocketIn.bind(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.LocalHost, 2340, QtNetwork.QUdpSocket.ReuseAddressHint)
self.SocketIn.readyRead.connect(lambda: print("Hallo")
```

and (on c++ side)

```
SocketOut->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2340, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);
```

Both applications return true and the states are also "4", which means they are in BoundState.

Now the problem:
If I start at first the python application it is working. The c++ app receives messages on port 2341 and sends messages on 2340. The python app receives messages on port 2340 and sends messages on port 2341.
If I start the c++ application first, the python app won't trigger the readyRead signal on port 2340 anymore. Like I said all boundStates are there (python app, c++ app, -> ports 2340, 2341) and the messages are really send from the c++ app (seen in wireshark)

What is the clue here?

EDIT:
Now i realized that the other way around is the same behaviour. **It seems that the receiving side must be initialized first in order to work!**

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue here.  The code shown has both the python *and* c++ examples binding to port 2340.

Comment: That's right, Both must be bound to 2340, otherwise the python app won't understand the messages from the c++ side

Comment: Got here hoping to find a MWE. Please close this as not useful to anyone else

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The QUdpSocket documentation states

> If you just want to send datagrams, you don’t need to call bind() .

When I removed the bind from the sending side, I could start and stop the sender and receiver in any order and it worked.